# Is it possible to convert string to custom format that is defined as a regex pattern?

Tags: c#, regex, string-formatting

Used regex only to match strings not converting, so maybe question will be really stupid, but anyway:

Lets say I have a phone number: `+7771234567`
I have a regex pattern:  `^[+][0-9]\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4}$`
How do I make a phone number to look like: `+777-123-4567` ?

Thank you

Comment: `+7771234567` is this a strict format for a phone number? Will it always come in this format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your string will **always** be a `+` sign followed by 10 digits, you can use something like so:

```
String str = @"+7771234567";
            System.Console.WriteLine(new Regex(@"^([+])(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$").Replace(str, "$1$2-$3-$4"));
```

Will yield:

> +777-123-4567

What I am doing is that I am capturing your digit groups into regex groups and accessing them later through the `$` operator.